# Is $\{a^m!a^n : n > 0, m > 0, n > m\}$ a context free language?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm trying to construct a context-free grammar for the language $L = \{a^m!a^n : n > 0, m > 0, n > m\}$, but I'm not sure how to ensure that the right trail of $a$s is longer than the left one.

Is there a way I could include the left side in the right side using context-free grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could look at the language as strings of the form $a^n!a^ka^n.$ Guided by this insight we could use the CFG with productions $S\rightarrow aSa\ |\ a!Ta,\quad T\rightarrow aT\ |\ a$. We're generating strings of the form $a^n\dots a^n$ and then finishing off by placing $!a^k$ in the middle. This idiom of "constructing the outside part and then finishing with the interior" is fairly common in CFG construction.